# Connecting two router/access points

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

I have a Dlink DIR-825 access point in my house , and it is connected to a ADSL modem with PPPOE. However, I want to have a network in another building, so I bought a TPLink Archer C5 access point and connected a Ethernet cable from LAN port of Dlink to WAN port of Archer.

It is working, but I want to see the Dlink clients from C5 
for example, my PC is connected to the LAN port of C5 and I have some shared folders that I want to access from my tablet, which is connected to Dlink.

Or, my phone is connected to C5 , and I want to access some files on another device which is connected wirelessly to Dlink. How can such a task be accomplished?

Here are some pictures from Dlink and C5 setup:

[Gallery of screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UETpx.jpg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the WAN port.
Disable DHCP on the second router if you have it activated.

With this setup you have created a separate network with your Archer (including, probably another layer of NAT). You'll want that the Archer is more acting like a 'Switch' than another router.

Comment: What IP should I use on the second router when i disable DHCP ?
Will I be able to connect clients wirelessly and with ethernet cable ? or does it need some specific configuration?

Comment: One you like. Preferable one that doesn't collide with the DHCP range from your Dlink.
yes/no to the other questions.